# A Vim script that checks capital letters and makes necessary corrections

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a script that would check the beginning of a paragraph and first character after sentence's terminal (.,?,!), and then it would capitalize required letters.

Thank you for help.

Comment: I'd suggest you additionally require a space after the terminal (*hxxp://www.Google.Com*). Still not perfect (*Yahoo! employees*), but fewer false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
%s/\(^\|[.?!] \+\)./\U&/g
```

Explanation:

```
`%` - for every line in the file
`s/` - substitute
`\( \| \)` - a group of alternatives
`^` - after a newline (beginning of paragraph)
`[.?!] \+` - after a terminal punctuation mark and one or more required spaces
`.` - any character (it's not necessary, but you could use `[[:alpha:]]` instead)
`/` - replacement
`\U` - uppercase the following string (it will only affect the `[[:alpha:]]` character
`/g` - end of command and make it apply to every match on a line
```