# How to add auto-cap string to .vimrc?

Tags: vim, embedded

This is in reply to:

[**A Vim script that checks capital letters and makes necessary corrections**](https://superuser.com/q/233594/128997)

that I found useful.  I am a confirmed CLI hacker and writer.  Because my fingers know Vim, I use it.  In fact, I'm lost without it.  How do I add the one-liner Vim script in my `~/.vimrc`?  Note, that I have tried a few things with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you tried and how they didn't work, but if you just want to run that command with a single keystroke, you could put this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
map <F2> :%s/\(^\\|[.?!] \+\)./\U&/g<CR>
```

Note that I copied the command from the answer you referred to in your question but I had to double the backslash (`\`) in front of the bar (`|`) to get it to work. You might also read

```
:help usr_40.txt
```

for more on defining your own commands in Vim.